# Scraping udemy gives 403 error using python requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, http-status-code-403, http-error

I tried scraping udemy course data using python requests.

python = 3.8

requests = 2.23.0

```
headers={'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'cache-control': 'no-cache',
'pragma': 'no-cache',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8',
'sec-ch-ua-platform': "Windows",
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36'}

from requests import session

session = session()

resp=session.get('https://www.udemy.com/course/design-thinking-product-development',headers=headers)
```

Here I got status 403 along with some byte text like the following (truncated):

> b'\x13\x962\x00d\xbe_\xcb\xff\xfe\xfb\xe7\xab\xaeof\x92\x1cc\xb3\xac\x9at\xdfQ\x11\xc1\x15\x01E\x99\xa5O\x01\xc5\xb2\x15K\x01b\xde=

Please help me fix this issue. To let you know, I tried using all user-agents possible but they all ended up giving 403 error.

Comment: i'm getting an ok response with no headers

Comment: what data are you after. They have an api you know

Comment: thanks @diggusbickus, but why is not working with headers?

Comment: it's your user-agent that is forbidden maybe too old, dunno. for faking user-agents use [`Faker`](https://pypi.org/project/Faker/)

Comment: Sometimes unnecessary headers create 403 errors

Comment: that's my chrome user-agent so how can it be old? I copied it from chrome inspect @diggusbickus

Comment: i said i don't know. but i kept all your headers and changed user-agent and got 200 again

Comment: I copied all the headers that are in the chrome inspect @Fazlul

Comment: what user-agent you used @diggusbickus?

Comment: I removed headers completely and got 200 as well. Again, why not use the api?

Comment: To inject user-agent  as headers is enough

Comment: the first faker gave me was `Opera/9.55.(Windows 95; ckb-IQ) Presto/2.9.175 Version/10.00` windows 95 lol, obviously it's not an old-related question

Comment: I am new to web scraping just learning @chitown88